# COUNT OVER PARTITION in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, business-intelligence, ssas-tabular

I need a basic conversion from SQL to DAX for the count field. It seems so simple yet I could not figure it out. I could not find it anywhere either.

```
SELECT EMAIL,COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY EMAIL) EmailCount
FROM FactSales
WHERE EMAIL IS NOT NULL

SalesID     EMAIL           EmailCount
1           a@hotmail.com   3
1           a@hotmail.com   3
2           a@hotmail.com   3
3           b@gmail.com     2
4           b@gmail.com     2
6           c@yahoo.com     4
7           c@yahoo.com     4
7           c@yahoo.com     4
7           c@yahoo.com     4
```

Thanks in advance for any replies

Answer (score 0):

A DAX function for this is not necessary. If you only want to visualize the amount of email you have to drag the email column into your visualization and select the option COUNT. 
However if you need the DAX for this expression should be something like this:

```
AmountOfEmail = CALCULATE ( COUNT ( FactSales[email] ), NOT ( ISBLANK ( FactSales[email] ) ) )
```

Comment: I wish it was that simple but i'm afraid that's not what i'm looking for exactly. I would like to be able to produce the results in the original post if that makes sense.

Comment: Now I understand your problem.
What you have to do is create a new index column using power query for your table.
Then you have to create the following measure: 
    EmailCount = CALCULATE( COUNT( 'Table'[Email] ),  ALLEXCEPT( 'Table', 'Table'[Email] ) )
Then drop the index, salesid, email and the measure into the table visual and you will see the same result.
Hope it helps.

Comment: One more question regarding this. In terms of efficiency and cost, which one would you prefer to handle this? SQL or DAX? We are talking about a table of 20 million rows roughly.

Comment: Without doubt I would use SQL as much as I can to obtain all needed data. 
Doing that you wont be forced to create an index column and you wont use ram memory to calculate that expected result using dax.